# HazelcastSerializationException: When Jet job is running over multiple cluster

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I am trying to run one of the Hazelcast-jet [example](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/3.2-maintenance/core-api/prime-finder/src/main/java/PrimeFinder.java) over a Distributed System. My objective is to run code over Disributed System, Utilize Multiple machine's processing power. I have two Laptops connected via LAN. When I run this example in One Machine it works fine, to run it both system I Start Machine 1 and Machine 2 with only jet Instance. code on both Machines are,

**Machine 1**

```
public class PrimeFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "log4j");
        try {
            JetConfig cfg = new JetConfig();
            cfg.setInstanceConfig(new InstanceConfig().setCooperativeThreadCount(
                    Math.max(1, getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2)));
            cfg.setProperty("hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size","3");
            Jet.newJetInstance(cfg);
            JetInstance jet = Jet.newJetInstance(cfg);

            DAG dag = new DAG();

            final int limit = 15_485_864;
            Vertex generator = dag.newVertex("number-generator", new GenerateNumbersMetaSupplier(limit));
            Vertex primeChecker = dag.newVertex("filter-primes", filterP(PrimeFinder::isPrime));
            Vertex writer = dag.newVertex("writer", writeListP("primes"));

            dag.edge(between(generator, primeChecker));
            dag.edge(between(primeChecker, writer));

            jet.newJob(dag).join();

            IListJet<Integer> primes = jet.getList("primes");
            List<Integer> sortedPrimes = primes.stream().sorted().limit(1000).collect(toList());
            System.out.println("Found " + primes.size() + " primes.");
            System.out.println("Some of the primes found are: " + sortedPrimes);

        } finally {
            Jet.shutdownAll();
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }

        int endValue = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
        for (int i = 2; i <= endValue; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static class GenerateNumbersMetaSupplier implements ProcessorMetaSupplier {

        private final int limit;

        private transient int totalParallelism;
        private transient int localParallelism;

        GenerateNumbersMetaSupplier(int limit) {
            this.limit = limit;
        }

        @Override
        public void init(@Nonnull Context context) {
            totalParallelism = context.totalParallelism();
            localParallelism = context.localParallelism();
        }


        @Override @Nonnull
        public Function<Address, ProcessorSupplier> get(@Nonnull List<Address> addresses) {
            Map<Address, ProcessorSupplier> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
                Address address = addresses.get(i);
                int start = i * localParallelism;
                int end = (i + 1) * localParallelism;
                int mod = totalParallelism;
                map.put(address, count -> range(start, end)
                        .mapToObj(index -> new GenerateNumbersP(range(0, limit).filter(f -> f % mod == index)))
                        .collect(toList())
                );
            }
            return map::get;
        }
    }

    static class GenerateNumbersP extends AbstractProcessor {

        private final Traverser<Integer> traverser;

        GenerateNumbersP(IntStream stream) {
            traverser = traverseStream(stream.boxed());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean complete() {
            return emitFromTraverser(traverser);
        }
    }

}
```

**Machine 2**

```
public class PrimeFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "log4j");
        try {
            JetConfig cfg = new JetConfig();
            cfg.setInstanceConfig(new InstanceConfig().setCooperativeThreadCount(
                    Math.max(1, getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2)));

            Jet.newJetInstance(cfg);
            JetInstance jet = Jet.newJetInstance(cfg);
        } 
    }
```

**Error**

```
Members {size:4, ver:4} [
    Member [192.168.43.5]:5701 - e9ff45b4-50a2-4918-b51f-9fc3012cce7c
    Member [192.168.43.224]:5701 - 5931daa7-4452-4275-a3d5-a9daaf247f50
    Member [192.168.43.224]:5702 - 57bce3eb-71f7-40d3-86b3-64481feb84e9
    Member [192.168.43.5]:5702 - 9fff0e81-748d-4774-8556-2f45941bd59d this
]

06:10,158 [192.168.43.5]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Starting job 0368-8053-f940-0004 based on submit request
06:12,285 [192.168.43.5]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Didn't find any snapshot to restore for job '0368-8053-f940-0004', execution 0368-8056-5ec0-0001
06:12,286 [192.168.43.5]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Start executing job '0368-8053-f940-0004', execution 0368-8056-5ec0-0001, execution graph in DOT format:
digraph DAG {
    "number-generator" [tooltip="local-parallelism=2"];
    "filter-primes" [tooltip="local-parallelism=2"];
    "writer" [tooltip="local-parallelism=1"];
    "number-generator" -> "filter-primes";
    "filter-primes" -> "writer";
}
HINT: You can use graphviz or http://viz-js.com to visualize the printed graph.
06:12,733 [192.168.43.5]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Execution plan for jobId=0368-8053-f940-0004, jobName='0368-8053-f940-0004', executionId=0368-8056-5ec0-0001 initialized
06:12,784 [192.168.43.5]:5702 [jet] [3.2] Execution plan for jobId=0368-8053-f940-0004, jobName='0368-8053-f940-0004', executionId=0368-8056-5ec0-0001 initialized
06:12,824 [192.168.43.5]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Execution of job '0368-8053-f940-0004', execution 0368-8056-5ec0-0001 failed after 648 ms
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleException(SerializationUtil.java:70)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:275)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:574)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.CustomClassLoadedObject.read(CustomClassLoadedObject.java:56)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.VertexDef.readData(VertexDef.java:153)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:269)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:574)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.ImdgUtil.readList(ImdgUtil.java:444)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.ExecutionPlan.readData(ExecutionPlan.java:307)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:187)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.CustomClassLoadedObject.deserializeWithCustomClassLoader(CustomClassLoadedObject.java:65)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.operation.InitExecutionOperation.deserializePlan(InitExecutionOperation.java:116)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.operation.InitExecutionOperation.run(InitExecutionOperation.java:71)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:210)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:199)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:416)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:153)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:123)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:110)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type.....
```

When I run this code on a single Machine, Example is working fine and output is as expected.

```
Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [172.29.97.33]:5701 - e2e6a9d5-9bdd-49d4-934c-e7becee8ad58
    Member [172.29.97.33]:5702 - 9e121fda-ca89-4d8c-a20e-3e345ce91fc2 this
]

36:20,086 [172.29.97.33]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Starting job 0368-94f5-7bc0-0002 based on submit request
36:20,316 [172.29.97.33]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Didn't find any snapshot to restore for job '0368-94f5-7bc0-0002', execution 0368-94f7-a640-0001
36:20,316 [172.29.97.33]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Start executing job '0368-94f5-7bc0-0002', execution 0368-94f7-a640-0001, execution graph in DOT format:
digraph DAG {
    "number-generator" [tooltip="local-parallelism=2"];
    "filter-primes" [tooltip="local-parallelism=2"];
    "writer" [tooltip="local-parallelism=1"];
    "number-generator" -> "filter-primes";
    "filter-primes" -> "writer";
}
HINT: You can use graphviz or http://viz-js.com to visualize the printed graph.
36:21,185 [172.29.97.33]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Execution plan for jobId=0368-94f5-7bc0-0002, jobName='0368-94f5-7bc0-0002', executionId=0368-94f7-a640-0001 initialized
36:21,237 [172.29.97.33]:5702 [jet] [3.2] Execution plan for jobId=0368-94f5-7bc0-0002, jobName='0368-94f5-7bc0-0002', executionId=0368-94f7-a640-0001 initialized
36:21,250 [172.29.97.33]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Start execution of job '0368-94f5-7bc0-0002', execution 0368-94f7-a640-0001 from coordinator [172.29.97.33]:5701
36:21,327 [172.29.97.33]:5702 [jet] [3.2] Start execution of job '0368-94f5-7bc0-0002', execution 0368-94f7-a640-0001 from coordinator [172.29.97.33]:5701
37:11,263 [172.29.97.33]:5701 [jet] [3.2] Execution of job '0368-94f5-7bc0-0002', execution 0368-94f7-a640-0001 completed in 51,171 ms
Found 1000000 primes.
Some of the primes found are: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499, 1511, 1523, 1531, 1543, 1549, 1553, 1559, 1567, 1571, 1579, 1583, 1597, 1601, 1607, 1609, 1613, 1619, 1621, 1627, 1637, 1657, 1663, 1667, 1669, 1693, 1697, 1699, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1733, 1741, 1747, 1753, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1787, 1789, 1801, 1811, 1823, 1831, 1847, 1861, 1867, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1879, 1889, 1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987, 1993, 1997, 1999, 2003, 2011, 2017, 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 2099, 2111, 2113, 2129, 2131, 2137, 2141, 2143, 2153, 2161, 2179, 2203, 2207, 2213, 2221, 2237, 2239, 2243, 2251, 2267, 2269, 2273, 2281, 2287, 2293, 2297, 2309, 2311, 2333, 2339, 2341, 2347, 2351, 2357, 2371, 2377, 2381, 2383, 2389, 2393, 2399, 2411, 2417, 2423, 2437, 2441, 2447, 2459, 2467, 2473, 2477, 2503, 2521, 2531, 2539, 2543, 2549, 2551, 2557, 2579, 2591, 2593, 2609, 2617, 2621, 2633, 2647, 2657, 2659, 2663, 2671, 2677, 2683, 2687, 2689, 2693, 2699, 2707, 2711, 2713, 2719, 2729, 2731, 2741, 2749, 2753, 2767, 2777, 2789, 2791, 2797, 2801, 2803, 2819, 2833, 2837, 2843, 2851, 2857, 2861, 2879, 2887, 2897, 2903, 2909, 2917, 2927, 2939, 2953, 2957, 2963, 2969, 2971, 2999, 3001, 3011, 3019, 3023, 3037, 3041, 3049, 3061, 3067, 3079, 3083, 3089, 3109, 3119, 3121, 3137, 3163, 3167, 3169, 3181, 3187, 3191, 3203, 3209, 3217, 3221, 3229, 3251, 3253, 3257, 3259, 3271, 3299, 3301, 3307, 3313, 3319, 3323, 3329, 3331, 3343, 3347, 3359, 3361, 3371, 3373, 3389, 3391, 3407, 3413, 3433, 3449, 3457, 3461, 3463, 3467, 3469, 3491, 3499, 3511, 3517, 3527, 3529, 3533, 3539, 3541, 3547, 3557, 3559, 3571, 3581, 3583, 3593, 3607, 3613, 3617, 3623, 3631, 3637, 3643, 3659, 3671, 3673, 3677, 3691, 3697, 3701, 3709, 3719, 3727, 3733, 3739, 3761, 3767, 3769, 3779, 3793, 3797, 3803, 3821, 3823, 3833, 3847, 3851, 3853, 3863, 3877, 3881, 3889, 3907, 3911, 3917, 3919, 3923, 3929, 3931, 3943, 3947, 3967, 3989, 4001, 4003, 4007, 4013, 4019, 4021, 4027, 4049, 4051, 4057, 4073, 4079, 4091, 4093, 4099, 4111, 4127, 4129, 4133, 4139, 4153, 4157, 4159, 4177, 4201, 4211, 4217, 4219, 4229, 4231, 4241, 4243, 4253, 4259, 4261, 4271, 4273, 4283, 4289, 4297, 4327, 4337, 4339, 4349, 4357, 4363, 4373, 4391, 4397, 4409, 4421, 4423, 4441, 4447, 4451, 4457, 4463, 4481, 4483, 4493, 4507, 4513, 4517, 4519, 4523, 4547, 4549, 4561, 4567, 4583, 4591, 4597, 4603, 4621, 4637, 4639, 4643, 4649, 4651, 4657, 4663, 4673, 4679, 4691, 4703, 4721, 4723, 4729, 4733, 4751, 4759, 4783, 4787, 4789, 4793, 4799, 4801, 4813, 4817, 4831, 4861, 4871, 4877, 4889, 4903, 4909, 4919, 4931, 4933, 4937, 4943, 4951, 4957, 4967, 4969, 4973, 4987, 4993, 4999, 5003, 5009, 5011, 5021, 5023, 5039, 5051, 5059, 5077, 5081, 5087, 5099, 5101, 5107, 5113, 5119, 5147, 5153, 5167, 5171, 5179, 5189, 5197, 5209, 5227, 5231, 5233, 5237, 5261, 5273, 5279, 5281, 5297, 5303, 5309, 5323, 5333, 5347, 5351, 5381, 5387, 5393, 5399, 5407, 5413, 5417, 5419, 5431, 5437, 5441, 5443, 5449, 5471, 5477, 5479, 5483, 5501, 5503, 5507, 5519, 5521, 5527, 5531, 5557, 5563, 5569, 5573, 5581, 5591, 5623, 5639, 5641, 5647, 5651, 5653, 5657, 5659, 5669, 5683, 5689, 5693, 5701, 5711, 5717, 5737, 5741, 5743, 5749, 5779, 5783, 5791, 5801, 5807, 5813, 5821, 5827, 5839, 5843, 5849, 5851, 5857, 5861, 5867, 5869, 5879, 5881, 5897, 5903, 5923, 5927, 5939, 5953, 5981, 5987, 6007, 6011, 6029, 6037, 6043, 6047, 6053, 6067, 6073, 6079, 6089, 6091, 6101, 6113, 6121, 6131, 6133, 6143, 6151, 6163, 6173, 6197, 6199, 6203, 6211, 6217, 6221, 6229, 6247, 6257, 6263, 6269, 6271, 6277, 6287, 6299, 6301, 6311, 6317, 6323, 6329, 6337, 6343, 6353, 6359, 6361, 6367, 6373, 6379, 6389, 6397, 6421, 6427, 6449, 6451, 6469, 6473, 6481, 6491, 6521, 6529, 6547, 6551, 6553, 6563, 6569, 6571, 6577, 6581, 6599, 6607, 6619, 6637, 6653, 6659, 6661, 6673, 6679, 6689, 6691, 6701, 6703, 6709, 6719, 6733, 6737, 6761, 6763, 6779, 6781, 6791, 6793, 6803, 6823, 6827, 6829, 6833, 6841, 6857, 6863, 6869, 6871, 6883, 6899, 6907, 6911, 6917, 6947, 6949, 6959, 6961, 6967, 6971, 6977, 6983, 6991, 6997, 7001, 7013, 7019, 7027, 7039, 7043, 7057, 7069, 7079, 7103, 7109, 7121, 7127, 7129, 7151, 7159, 7177, 7187, 7193, 7207, 7211, 7213, 7219, 7229, 7237, 7243, 7247, 7253, 7283, 7297, 7307, 7309, 7321, 7331, 7333, 7349, 7351, 7369, 7393, 7411, 7417, 7433, 7451, 7457, 7459, 7477, 7481, 7487, 7489, 7499, 7507, 7517, 7523, 7529, 7537, 7541, 7547, 7549, 7559, 7561, 7573, 7577, 7583, 7589, 7591, 7603, 7607, 7621, 7639, 7643, 7649, 7669, 7673, 7681, 7687, 7691, 7699, 7703, 7717, 7723, 7727, 7741, 7753, 7757, 7759, 7789, 7793, 7817, 7823, 7829, 7841, 7853, 7867, 7873, 7877, 7879, 7883, 7901, 7907, 7919]
37:21,664 [172.29.97.33]:5702 [jet] [3.2] Removing connection to endpoint [172.29.97.33]:5701 Cause => java.net.SocketException {Connection refused: no further information to address /172.29.97.33:5701}, Error-Count: 5
37:21,697 [172.29.97.33]:5702 [jet] [3.2] Member [172.29.97.33]:5701 - e2e6a9d5-9bdd-49d4-934c-e7becee8ad58 is suspected to be dead for reason: No connection
37:21,697 [172.29.97.33]:5702 [jet] [3.2] Starting mastership claim process...
37:21,698 [172.29.97.33]:5702 [jet] [3.2] Local MembersView{version=2, members=[MemberInfo{address=[172.29.97.33]:5701, uuid=e2e6a9d5-9bdd-49d4-934c-e7becee8ad58, liteMember=false, memberListJoinVersion=1}, MemberInfo{address=[172.29.97.33]:5702, uuid=9e121fda-ca89-4d8c-a20e-3e345ce91fc2, liteMember=false, memberListJoinVersion=2}]} with suspected members: [[172.29.97.33]:5701] and initial addresses to ask: []
37:21,772 [172.29.97.33]:5702 [jet] [3.2] 

Members {size:1, ver:3} [
    Member [172.29.97.33]:5702 - 9e121fda-ca89-4d8c-a20e-3e345ce91fc2 this
]

37:21,773 [172.29.97.33]:5702 [jet] [3.2] Mastership is claimed with: MembersView{version=3, members=[MemberInfo{address=[172.29.97.33]:5702, uuid=9e121fda-ca89-4d8c-a20e-3e345ce91fc2, liteMember=false, memberListJoinVersion=2}]}
```

Can anyone help me out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any other Example that I can run using Hazelcast jet over Distributed System is also Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the class to the `JobConfig` and pass it when submitting the pipeline:

```java
JobConfig jobConfig = new JobConfig();
jobConfig.addClass(PrimeFinder.class);

jet.newJob(dag, jobConfig).join();
```

Comment: It worked! I still have one doubt though, Why JobConfig did not need when I run this code on Single Machine with two(multi) jet Instance?

Comment: They are in the same JVM so the class is known to both Jet instances

Comment: Each member either (1) needs to have the job classes on its classpath or (2) the classes must be added to JobConfig to be deployed to members or a combination of these two. You can create a JAR file from your job classes and add them to the member classpath, this is especially efficient if you submit a small batch jobs many times because Jet doesn't have to load the classes over and over. Or you can put a library you use to member CP, but not the job, this allows you to change the job code without member restart etc.